# Should I upgrade Ubuntu from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS on Asus X205TA

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, asus

I have X205TA following the instruction over here and other forums I have sucessfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my asus X205TA via using answers from this forum, infact I am even running a samba server out of it. My main issue is I found ubuntu prompting to upgrade to LTS v18.04 now and then so

1. is it safe to upgrade via terminal without breaking up my wifi and other systems?
2. if you are running 18.04 how is the performance ? is it better than 16.04?
3. or should I stick to 16.04 only?

p.s - This laptop has a 32Gb emmc and no hdd, It has a 32bit boot loader but a currently running 64bit os with 64bit processor but some how due to good community (thanks to harryharryharry) has written a script to make that work.

so will it be safe to run an upgrade via terminal?

Comment: You haven't said if you're talking about a desktop? or a server?  Why don't you try Ubuntu 18.04 on your actual hardware before you make a decision (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0), but be aware Ubuntu 16.04 LTS reaches the end of it's support life in 2021-April  so you still have time, but I'd also consider your applications/programs used, as 'universe' software is mostly EOL or no-longer patched for 16.04 (use `ubuntu-support-status` on your own system to see what % of packages you have installed are still supported, are no longer supported etc)

Comment: "so will it be safe to run an upgrade via terminal?" You understand we expect you to make backups of personal files? Then why ask this? "Should I" Not of our concern sorry. YOU decide if you should. No-one else in the world is capable of answering that question besides you. At least... unless you legally do not  have the "capacity to consent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe now to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 from the terminal. I don't think Ubuntu 18.04's performance is going to be that different from 16.04. I don't expect that there would be any issues with the ASUS EeeBook X205TA's wireless adaptor as a result of upgrading to 18.04.

The most important advantage of the upgrade is that Ubuntu 18.04 Extended Security Maintenance (ESM) support lifespan extends Ubuntu 18.04 support from 5 years to 10 years. That means that you won't have to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to a newer release until 2028.

[Extended Security Maintenance](https://ubuntu.com/esm) (ESM) is free for personal use on up to 3 machines (some limitations apply). All you need is an Ubuntu One account.

[image]

Comment: Might it help to include the route to Ubuntu Advantage Infrastructure Essential (ESM) for completeness?