# Ubuntu partitioning: How to install Ubuntu 20.04 along side with already installed Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb, gparted

on my HP laptop, Ubuntu 21.04 is installed.
I wanna partition my disk to have both Ubuntu 21.04 and 20.04.
So I made a booting USB and plugged it to partition the existing disk into two.
However, when booting through the USB, `gparted` in "Try Ubuntu" mode cannot detect the other disk.

How can I fix it? Or, I don't want it, but can I remove the Ubuntu 21.04 and just install Ubuntu 20.04?

- When booting on laptop disk
  [image]
- When booting on USB disk
  [image]

Comment: Where did you obtain Ubuntu? I can see from your screenshot that your live USB is either outdated or it is not genuine Ubuntu. The currently available version of Ubuntu 20.04 is 20.04.4.  So I would start by ensuring that you have valid, up-to-date installation media.

Comment: Your installed 21.04 is using the 5.11 kernel stack, however your picture shows an older kernel in *live* mode, ie. what is likely only a 5.8 kernel which is no longer *supported*  (5.4 is the *supported* GA kernel, or HWE is currently 5.13).   Your difference is likely the kernel & likely *oudated* media as @Nmath has already suggested - did you scan the kernel boot logs?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The booting USB was made a while ago, so it might be the problem. I'll try it again. Now, I forgot to bring the battery charger, so I can try it next week :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does upgrading Ubuntu via a stick destroy existing files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271653/does-upgrading-ubuntu-via-a-stick-destroy-existing-files)

Comment: Do you want the same data in both systems? Best not to share /home as that includes user settings that you may not want the same or are incompatible. But you can create a data partition, copy/move data into it, and mount it in both installs. Shrink current install. Create new partiiton for / & large partition for data. you then later can install 22.04 over obsolete 21.04 and mount data into it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Thank you all, the problem was the outdated image on the USB.
Also, installing a different version alongside the other is pretty easy cuz Ubuntu installer provides the functionality by default!